# Casting from Any to another class returns null in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I have a dynamic Json and I am trying to parse it like this

```
obs.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe(object: Observer <Response<Any>> {
        override fun onComplete() {}

        override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {}

        override fun onNext(t: Response<Any>) {
            if (t.code() != 400) {
                val registerResponse = t.body() as RegisterResponse?
                    //this is null
                    println("value of register resp " + registerResponse?.status)
                liveData.value = t.body() as RegisterResponse ?

            } else {
                val validationError = t.body() as ValidationError?
                    //this is also null
                    println("error resp " + validationError?.message?.password?.get(0))
                error.value = t.body() as ValidationError?
            }
        }

        override fun onError(e: Throwable) {}

})
```

I am trying to get a generic Response as Any and then if the response returns a valid response I cast it to RegisterResponse and if it returns error then I cast it to ValidationError response. But when I am doing this, it is returning null every time. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can u print t.body() before casting and show the data ?

Comment: `body()` is nullable in the code. Make sure you get a non-null response. Also, print `t.body()::class.java` to check the class you're getting.

Comment: If you cast something with `as` and get null, you had null before the cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Any` specifies and assures your instance `t` is not `NULL`.  The only explanation is that `t.body()` **is** `null`, and that it is a `nullable type`. There is not enough info here to solve why.

If your are certain it should not be, cast to non-null types

```
val registerResponse = t.body() as RegisterResponse
val validationError = t.body() as ValidationError
```

That will make your code **much cleaner** downstream as well, and you can remove all the null guards.

You will also get an exception instead of falling through.